# jQuery mobile popup on pageinit

Tags: jquery-mobile, page-init

I want a popup to open as soon as the page loads but seem to be getting stuck with the spinning wheel.

Here is a fiddler to demonstrate the problem any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ohpyx/UGfXG/

The code I'm using is:

```
$(document).live('pageinit',function(event){
    $('#popupBasic').popup('open');
})​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.ui-page',function(event){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#popupBasic').popup('open');
    }, 0);//Note the comment below from @Taifun.
})​
```

You had a race condition and this places the popup code at the end of the queue.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UGfXG/6/

Note: I replaced `.live()` with `.on()` (the delegated flavor) as the former has been depreciated as of jQuery 1.7.

Comment: you should set the timeout > 0 to get this running, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13240507/1545993...

Comment: @Taifun I tested in Chrome and Android browsers which worked fine, so thanks for the catch on other browsers. Firefox didn't work for me, but when I changed the delay to `100ms`, it worked.

Comment: Ah, this is fantastic thanks folks. I read in the documentation about using timeouts with chaining but the reasoning didn't grasp with me. Now I am beginning to understand and will probably spend my evening googling into this more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `.popup('open')` needs the `$.mobile.activePage`, which is set after the `pageinit` event. The `pagechange` event seems to be better for popups.

This worked for me :

```
$(document).on('pagechange',function(event){
    $('#popupBasic').popup('open');
})​
```

If you want it just at the first load, use `.one` :

```
$(document).one('pagechange',function(event){
    $('#popupBasic').popup('open');
})​
```

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3384