# jQuery Mobile popup on page load with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I am trying to open a popup on page load using jQuery Mobile and Rails.

The popup can be opened with a link, but  I can't make it open on load.

HTML code

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup-choix" data-history="false" data-overlay-theme="a" data-transition="flow" data-position-to="window">
    <ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function() {
  $('#popup-choix').popup('open'); 
});
```

I checked with Chrome and the Javascript is correctly linked to the page.

I have a link on the page to open the popup. It works perfectly.

```
<div class="div-popup"><a href="#popup-choix" data-rel="popup">...</a></div>
```

I guess the problem is with my Javascript then...

---

**UPDATE**

I placed the Javascript in `popup.js`, which is then called with the `application.js` manifest.

**UPDATE 2**

I wrote the javascript in [popup.js](https://github.com/BR41N1/Instavert/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/popup.js) and call it with the [manifest](https://github.com/BR41N1/Instavert/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js).

Comment: could you please post your code, of how you're calling it?

Comment: I added a link to my entire project.

Comment: Ill check it. Just do me a favor, add _console.log_ in the code u want to fire the popup and see if it fires.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your request. You want me to add `console.log` to `popup.js`?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/BR41N1/Instavert/blob/master/app/views/layouts/_jquerymobile.html.erb) instead of opening the popup, add `console.log('pop up test');`

Comment: Check my updated answer. I hope it works this time.

Comment: It is still not working! The code must work alone, but with Rails, it bugs for a reason... I think I'll simply show a growl-type message with a link to the popup...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27385/discussion-between-omar-and-justin-d)

Comment: @Omar, I can't access the chat through my school firewall. I just remembred Rails has a **public** folder. The html files located in this folder does not call the javacript/css I put in the manifest. With the code you give in your answer, I was able to make everything work.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for all the efforts you put into helping me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

> **Note:** for *Ruby on Rails* users read this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736855/jquery-mobile-popup-on-page-load-with-rails?noredirect=1#comment22447470_15736855).

This is the correct way to open a popup, once page loads/shows.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function() {
 $('#popup-choix').popup('open');
});
```

In some browsers, popup doesn't show once the page loads, therefore, adding timeout to open the popup is essential.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772868/jquery-mobile-popup-on-pageinit)

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
    $('#popup-choix').popup('open');
 }, 100); // delay above zero
});
```

If you want to open for a specific page, add `'#PageId'` instead of `document`.

Comment: Your solution works on jsFiddle, but I can't make it work with my project... Do you have any idea of what could cause the problem?

Comment: @JustinD. how do you call it in your code? can you post more details pls?

Comment: if you have the code in a separate file try `$(document).live("pageshow", "#PageID" , function()`. Does my previous code works inline with your HTML code?

Comment: It does not work either... Earlier today, I tried to put the code inline, but it didn't work either...

Comment: instead of `$(document)` add `$('[data-role=page]')`.