# JQuery callback functions fired before event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I don't know if I am doing some silly mistake here but facing this problem of firing callback functions on page init before actual event happens.
Here is the code

```
$(document).on("pageinit",function(){
$("#discInvitePopUp").popup({
        transition: "slidedown",
        history: false,
        afterclose: function( event, ui ) {

            activeDiscInviteCloseHandler();
        },
        afteropen: function( event, ui ) {
            openDiscFrmInvite();
        }
    });

}
```

here are the callback functions:

```
function activeDiscInviteCloseHandler(){
    //some code
    //curDiscInv set
    alert("evt");
    $.post("/ajaxReq/user_action.php", {
        unsetInvite:JSON.stringify(curDiscInv)
    }, function(data){


    });

}
function openDiscFrmInvite(){
   //some code
}
```

here problem is that

> activeDiscInviteCloseHandler()

function is called as soon as pageinit event is triggered as a result it sends post data to server which is not desirable.

Any possible solutions to avoid this.

Comment: This appears to be new functionality, and a similar problem has been noted on the jQuery mobile forums by one of the users there. Don't discount the possibility that you've come across a bug in jQuery mobile itself.

Comment: You need to `setTimeout` to open the popup. It fires twice on pageinit due to event occurrence during pages transition and delay caused by browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15738426/1771795

Comment: can you give us the whole code, maybe the jquery mobile will trigger close on page init so the popup is not displayed ?

Answer (score -3):

Instead of

```
$(document).on("pageinit",function()...
```

try

```
$(document).ready(function()...
```

Comment: jQuery( ".selector" ).on( "pageinit", function( event ) { ... } )

We recommend binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation system.