# .Show() not working in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm looking to simply hide and image before the page loads and then once the page has loaded to show the image. Problem is when I try to show the image it doesn't show the image at all.

Here is my html code:

```
<body>

    <div id ="splash" data-role="page">
        <center>
            <div id='class'> <img src="BookBayText.png"></div>
            <div id='book'> <img src="Book.png"></div>
        </center>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is my javascript/jquery mobile:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#splash',
            function()
            {
                $("#book").hide();
            });

        $(document).on('pageinit','#splash',
            function(){

                setTimeout(
                    function()
                    {
                        $("#class").animate({top: "1em"}, 'slow');
                    },3000);

                //For some reason this line below doesn't run
                $("#book").show();

        });
    </script>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working??

Comment: It's better to use CSS to hide something initially. Also, you can just use `$(function(){ $('#book').show(); });`

Comment: .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible as part of the effect.  http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I know the animate doesn't hide the image, I use the animate to move the BookBayText.png image upwards

Comment: I've changed the lines with .hide() and .show() to $("#book").css("visibility","hidden"); and $("#book").css("visibility","visible"); but for some reason it still doesn't add the css to the image. Is there a function I need to call to perhaps refresh the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the desired effect I wanted with the following code:

```
setTimeout(
   function()
   {
      $("#class").animate({top: "1em"}, 'slow');
      $("#book").show();
   },2000);
```

Basically I moved the `$("#book").show();` line into the setTimeout function. But it still leaves me a tad lost as to why the code wouldn't show the image outside the function. If anyone with the answer to this could update this answer it would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

kinda similar to this post [jQuery mobile popup on pageinit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772868/jquery-mobile-popup-on-pageinit/13773033#13773033) .

Although the post blames a delay in the browser, for me it is still unclear why it does it. I have never experience such behaviour.

1. I wonder what if you do the following changes:
2. put your center tag inside a data-role:content,
3. replace pageinit for pageshow.
4. search your iem as follows
   inside either pageinit or pageshow (not settimeout).

>

```
 var elem = $("[data-role='page']:last").find('#book img'); // others may use $.mobile.activePage

if (elem.length) {
   // check height or img width here...
}
```